# Rounding error in C++ Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am encountering a very weird functionality while trying to write my own rounding function in C++.

Both of the following functions produce 0.000 as an output.

```
double round ( double x, int y)
{
    double value = 0;

    value = floor(x*pow(10, y) + x>=0?0.5:-0.5)/pow(10, y);

    return value;
}

double round3(double x)
{
    double value = 0;

    value = floor(x * 1000 + x>=0?0.5:-0.5) / 1000;

    return value;
}
```

However this function produces correct output, rounding to 3 decimal places.

```
double round(double x)
{
    double value = 0;

    if (x >= 0){
        value = floor( x*1000 + 0.5 )/1000;
    }
    else{
        value = floor( x*1000 - 0.5 )/1000;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two have [operator precendence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) errors, e.g. `(x * 1000 + x>=0?0.5:-0.5) / 1000` is evaluated as `(((x * 1000 + x) >= 0) ? 0.5 : -0.5) / 1000`, so is 0.0005 when `x` is positive, and -0.0005 when `x` is negative.

Do keep in mind too that "rounding" of doubles is a tricky business... there can generally be errors around the 15th or 16th digit, whether because the "mathematically perfect" result of the operations you've performed can't be represented exactly in a `double` variable, or because of approximations in intermediate values or maths functions like `pow`, so you may find values you think of as being "n.5" are sometimes rounded up and sometimes down.  If confused by this, perhaps read [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator `?:` has a rather low priority, this

```
x * 1000 + x>=0?0.5:-0.5
```

is equivalent to:

```
(x * 1000 + x>=0)?0.5 :-0.5
```

which results as either `0.5` or `-0.5`.

Comment: thank you very much for this. I will put the ? in brackets to force it to behave as I expect it to